# How to set different name for an element in form and in preview webform?

Tags: webforms

I have generated this element:

```
addlabel_01:
      '#type': textfield
      '#title': 'Add label'
      '#maxlength': 2
      '#size': 160
      '#autocomplete': 'off'
```

and I need to show a different title in preview, from the one you see in the code which currently shows for both form and preview, let say it would be something like (which does not work by the way):

```
'#preview_title': 'Your label'
```